# install jbossws-cxf-3.4.0.GA on jboss51.GA and deploy webService

Tags: java, web-services, jboss5.x, jbossws

After upgrading to **jbossws-cxf-3.4.0.GA** on Jboss 5.1GA  **I can't deploy any webService** applications on this Jboss;

**java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jboss/wsf/common/KernelAwareSPIFactory** is written in log file.

The following error is thrown:

```
13:07:50,044 INFO  [EJBContainer] STOPPED EJB: ge.test.myWebService ejbName: myWebServicemyWebService 
13:07:50,044 INFO  [EJBContainer] STOPPED EJB: ge.test.myWebService ejbName: myWebService 
13:07:50,076 ERROR [AbstractKernelController] Error installing to Real: name=vfszip:/D:/jboss-5.1.0.GA/server/default/deploy/myWebService.ear/ state=PreReal mode=Manual requiredState=Real
org.jboss.deployers.spi.DeploymentException: Error during deploy: vfszip:/D:/JBoss/jboss-5.1.0.GA/server/default/deploy/myWebService.ear/services.jar/
    at org.jboss.deployers.spi.DeploymentException.rethrowAsDeploymentException(DeploymentException.java:49)
    ...
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jboss/wsf/common/KernelAwareSPIFactory
    ...
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jboss.wsf.common.KernelAwareSPIFactory from BaseClassLoader@fb7efa{VFSClassLoaderPolicy@14d82e1{name=vfszip:/D:/DevTool/JBoss/jboss-5.1.0.GA/server/default/deployers/jbossws-native-core.jar/ domain=ClassLoaderDomain@1931579{name=DefaultDomain parentPolicy=BEFORE parent=org.jboss.bootstrap.NoAnnotationURLClassLoader@15c7850} roots=[MemoryContextHandler@30122033[path= context=vfsmemory://5c4o01a-g18zic-hbrobclf-1-hbrobfz6-v real=vfsmemory://5c4o01a-g18zic-hbrobclf-1-hbrobfz6-v], DelegatingHandler@25305362[path=jbossws-native-core.jar context=file:/D:/DevTool/JBoss/jboss-5.1.0.GA/server/default/deployers/ real=file:/D:/JBoss/jboss-5.1.0.GA/server/default/deployers/jbossws-native-core.jar]]  delegates=null exported=[, org.jboss.ws.tools.helpers, org.jboss.ws.tools.factories, org.jboss.ws.tools.schema, org.jboss.ws.core.jaxws.wsaddressing, org.jboss.ws.extensions.wsrm.protocol.spec200502, org.jboss.ws.extensions.wsrm.protocol, schema, org.jboss.ws.extensions.wsrm.protocol.spec200702, org.jboss.wsf.stack.jbws, org.jboss.ws.metadata.builder.jaxrpc, org.jboss.ws.extensions.policy.deployer, org.jboss.ws.extensions.policy.metadata, org.jboss.ws.extensions.wsrm.transport, org.jboss.ws.extensions.policy, org.jboss.ws.core.client, org.jboss.ws.jaxrpc, org.jboss.ws.tools.wsdl, org.jboss.ws.extensions.addressing.jaxrpc, org.jboss.ws.extensions.wsrm.policy, org.jboss.ws.extensions.eventing.jaxws, org.jboss.ws.extensions.eventing.deployment, org.jboss.ws.extensions.security.operation, org.jboss.ws.extensions.security.exception, org.jboss.ws.extensions.policy.deployer.util, org.jboss.ws.core.jaxrpc, org.jboss.ws.util.xml, org.jboss.ws.extensions.addressing.jaxws, org.jboss.ws.extensions.validation, org.jboss.ws.metadata.config.jaxrpc, org.jboss.ws.extensions.xop.jaxws, org.jboss.ws.core.server, org.jboss.ws.metadata.wsdl.xsd, org.jboss.ws.core.jaxws.spi, org.jboss.ws.metadata.wsdl, org.jboss.ws.extensions.addressing, org.jboss.ws.annotation, META-INF.services, org.jboss.ws.extensions.xop.jaxrpc, org.jboss.ws.extensions.eventing, org.jboss.ws.extensions.addressing.metadata, org.jboss.ws.core.jaxrpc.handler, org.jboss.ws.extensions.json, org.jboss.ws.extensions.eventing.mgmt, META-INF.maven.org.jboss.ws.native.jbossws-native-core, org.jboss.ws.metadata.builder.jaxws, org.jboss.ws.metadata.config.jaxws, org.jboss.ws.tools.mapping, org.jboss.ws.extensions.security, org.jboss.ws.core.utils, org.jboss.ws.extensions.wsrm.persistence, org.jboss.ws.extensions.security.element, org.jboss.ws.extensions.wsrm, org.jboss.ws.tools.ant, org.jboss.ws.tools.config, org.jboss.ws.tools.exceptions, org.jboss.ws.core.soap, org.jboss.ws.metadata.wsse, org.jboss.ws.extensions.policy.deployer.domainAssertion, org.jboss.ws.tools.metadata, dtd, org.jboss.ws.core.jaxws.handler, org.jboss.ws.extensions.security.jaxws, org.jboss.ws.extensions.wsrm.server, org.jboss.ws.metadata.umdm, org.jboss.ws.metadata.wsdl.xmlschema, org.jboss.ws.tools, org.jboss.ws.extensions.wsrm.common, org.jboss.ws.extensions.addressing.soap, org.jboss.ws.core.jaxrpc.binding.jbossxb, org.jboss.ws.core.jaxws.binding, org.jboss.ws.metadata.accessor, org.jboss.ws.core, org.jboss.ws.metadata.config, org.jboss.ws.core.jaxws.client, org.jboss.ws.extensions.wsrm.config, org.jboss.ws.extensions.policy.annotation, org.jboss.ws.extensions.wsrm.transport.backchannel, org.jboss.ws.metadata.config.binding, org.jboss.ws.extensions.wsrm.api, org.jboss.ws.tools.client, org.jboss.ws.tools.interfaces, org.jboss.ws.extensions.eventing.metadata, org.jboss.ws.extensions.eventing.common, org.jboss.ws.extensions.security.nonce, org.jboss.ws.core.binding, org.jboss.ws.metadata.builder, org.jboss.ws.extensions.wsrm.protocol.spi, org.jboss.ws.extensions.xop, org.jboss.ws.core.jaxrpc.binding, org.jboss.ws.extensions.wsrm.jaxws, org.jboss.ws.extensions.policy.deployer.exceptions, org.jboss.ws.core.jaxrpc.client, org.jboss.ws.core.transport.jms, org.jboss.ws.core.jaxws, org.jboss.ws, META-INF, org.jboss.ws.extensions.security.jaxrpc, org.jboss.ws.metadata.jaxrpcmapping, org.jboss.ws.feature, org.jboss.ws.extensions.security.auth.callback, org.jboss.ws.extensions.wsrm.common.serialization, org.jboss.ws.core.soap.attachment, org.jboss.ws.tools.jaxws.impl] <IMPORT-ALL>NON_EMPTY}}
    ...
```

I've checked, **KernelAwareSPIFactory.class** isn't included in jbossws-common.jar of jbossws-cxf-3.4.0.GA. It was included in older one.

Should I upgrade any other library to deploy web services on my Jboss5.1GA? 

Or could you suggest any other solutions?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You may have read this already, but it looks like some sort of conflict with the cxf dependencies & the bootstrap loader, this link may help:

https://community.jboss.org/message/285554#285554

Regards

Comment: In my case, deployment doesn't work nor in server start-up neither with hot-deploy. org.jboss.wsf.common.KernelAwareSPIFactory class is missing in jbossws-common.jar. I think, that's why this error is thrown. But I don't know how to make it work

Comment: are you starting the server with the deployment already in /deploy? if so, try starting the service 1st, then add your deployment after everything is running